# Protected member is not accessible through a pointer or object c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

Visual studio is telling me I can't access a member variable from and instance of a parent class. Something like this:

```
class Point{
protected:
    int x, y;
};

class Quadrilateral : public Point
{
protected:
    Point A, B, C, D;
};

class Trapezoid : public Quadrilateral
{
public:
    bool isTrapezoid() {
        if (A.y == B.y && C.y == D.y)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

It's say that `Point::y` is not accessible through a pointer or object.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please post real code.

Comment: Also, 'pubic' inheritance is (thankfully) not a real thing.

Comment: Pubic functions are always a little tricky! ;-)

Comment: you dont need to inherit Point class in Quadrilateral. You can anyway use the Point Objects. and protected members are accessible from the class and derived class. So you may need to make x,y public

Comment: Maybe [friend classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Inheriting means you can access the protected member of the base class meaning in your case that Point::y can be used as Quadrilateral::y and Trapezoid::y inside the class, it doesn't mean that you can access y from any other Point object also not if they are members.
Inheriting from Point just to access A.y is wrong.
So Trapezoid can access A because of inheritance, but it can't access A.y because the accessibility of the members A has nothing to do with the inheritance in the question.

As Michael Walz commented, if you didn't want the members of Point to be public or accessible via member functions, you could declare Trapezoid as friend class of Point, which makes all members of Point accessible to Trapezoid.  However, misusing this can lead to unexpected issues.

Answer (score 0):

`Point` has protected members, no wonder they cannot be accessed. You should make them public.

Other points:

- `Quadrilateral` shouldn't inherit from `Point`, as that does not make sense.
- some syntax isn't real c++, you should fix it (e.g. `class class`,  code inside parameter list of `isTrapezoid`.
- make `isTrapezoid` to be a method that can be called on `Quadrilateral`, this should be a `const` method.
- for simple classes like that perhaps you should make all your members public (depending on your code design).

---

```
class Point
{
public:
    int x, y;
};

class Quadrilateral
{
public:
    Point a, b, c, d;

    bool isTrapezoid() const
    {
        return a.y == b.y && c.y == d.y;
    }
};
```